# Google static map showing blank when i loading large amount of custom markers

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, bigdata, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

here i am trying to print google static map with markers. When i am trying to load large amount (around 200 or more markers) of custom markers on google static map that time map is showing blank, here i reduced the marker icon url and lat,long length but when the data increases the issue resign again. please guide me to fix the issue and below i am giving my code. please helps to fix this issue.

var staticMapUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            staticMapUrl += "&center=" + "74.50262831227576" + "," + "87.00100900000007";
            staticMapUrl += "&size=900x1024";
            staticMapUrl += "&zoom=" + "5";
            staticMapUrl += "&maptype=" + 'roadmap';

```
        for (i in redata) {
            for (j in redata[i].industryvalues) {
                var image = redata[i].industryicon;
                var iconimage = redata[i].shorticon;
                var latitudee = redata[i].industryvalues[j].latitude;
                var longitudee = redata[i].industryvalues[j].longitude;
                staticMapUrl += "&markers=icon:" + iconimage + "|" + latitudee.substring(0,5) + "," + longitudee.substring(0,5);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will invite you to check the google Static Map API documentation specifically on the [size caps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#url-size-restriction) for non-premium users, which is 640x640. You can use the parameter **scale** to optimise for mobile viewers and different view-ports. Also the maptype roadmap is not really necessary because it is set as default.